# How to achieve progressive animate for svg line

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I am trying to achieve progressive animation for svg line path. I am using path like as M L M L ..... .. do to this problem the animation will not work perfectly.

Here is my code,

```js
var distancePerPoint = 1;
var drawFPS          = 100;

var orig = document.querySelector('path'), length, timer;
var a = document.querySelector('svg');
a.addEventListener('mouseover',startDrawingPath,false);
a.addEventListener('mouseout', stopDrawingPath, false);

function startDrawingPath(){
    length = 0;
    orig.style.stroke = 'green';
    timer = setInterval(increaseLength,600/drawFPS);
}

function increaseLength(a){
    var pathLength = orig.getTotalLength();
    length += distancePerPoint;
    orig.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", length + ' ,2000');
    if (length >= pathLength) clearInterval(timer);
}

function stopDrawingPath(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    orig.style.stroke = '';
}
```

```html
<svg id="asd" width="706" height="600">
    <path stroke="red" stroke-width="2" d="M 0 239.34 L 105.75 299.25 M 105.75 299.25 L 211.5 279.28 M 211.5 279.28 L 317.25 259.31 M 317.25 259.31 L 423 259.46 M 423 259.46 L 528.75 99.55 M 528.75 99.55 L 634.5 199.40000000000003 " />
</svg>
```

If I add line path as M L L L L mean it will work perfectly what I expected.. but I need this same behavior in M L M L M L...

how to achieve... without using css

Comment: Do you mean that you want the subpaths to animate one after the other, instead of all at the same time?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau just replace this path u can able to see the different 

"M 0 239.34 L 105.75 299.25 L 105.75 299.25 L 211.5 279.28 L 211.5 279.28 L 317.25 259.31 L 317.25 259.31 L 423 259.46 L 423 259.46 L 528.75 99.55 L 528.75 99.55 L 634.5 199.40000000000003 "

This what i need but using that path

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want the subpaths to animate one after the other, instead of all at the same time?

The answer is you can't.  The dash pattern begins/resets at the start of each subpath (each move 'M').  There is no way around this other than:

1. Fixing the path by removing the unnecessary 'M' commands, or
2. splitting the lines into separate paths, then triggering them one after another.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to animate the line using the 'stroke-dasharray' property. but that applies to each line primitive separately, and not the whole path. As you can see in the result. Every M component in the path will reset the internal stroke length values in the svg path renderer.

A more straight forward solution would be to animate the path data itself. Or just add path elements in the animation frame.